# making query using asyncdynamo

Tags: boto, amazon-dynamodb

I am using asyncdynamo library to interact with Amazon Dynamo DB. I can successfully get  items using get_item() but don't know how to format a query for it. I have tried different patterns but got no luck. The Library itself doesn't have any documentation to provide the information on this. 
If someone else has used and made queries using asyncdynamo then please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of documentation for Asyncdynamo really kills the usefulness of the project. You might consider using Dynochemy instead, since at least it has some examples:

https://github.com/rhettg/Dynochemy